# Downstream duration timeout databricks

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I am working on Azure Databricks in the GUI. I'm trying to upload a JAR file in the DBFS Filestore/jar which is 41 mb in size but midway in the upload I get the error `Downstream duration timeout`.

I'm not using any notebook so there is 0 code, all the work is being done in the user interface. Is there any solution to it?

Comment: can you please let me know what use case you are trying to achieve it here . as If you want to use any jar in your notebook, should be installed through cluster config .

Comment: I am trying the hands on given in this document, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/how-to-lineage-spark-atlas-connector. I was able to create the snapshot.jar and now I need to upload it to my databricks to continue the handson.

Comment: here context is little different. Databricks is Managed Spark in azure where as  pache Atlas connector Cloud-native Data Processing Tools in azure.

Comment: So is there no way for me to upload my JAR file in Azure databricks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cluster UI for this . but you should have CAN MANAGE access for your cluster .

[image]

[image]